# Origine del modo di dire "a detta di"

Tags: etymology

***[Detta](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/D/detta.shtml):***

> - usato solo nella locuzione  ***a detta  di***, secondo quel che dice: *a detta dell'avvocato la causa sarà presto discussa*

in realtà ***il termine detta ha altri [due](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/D/detta.php) significati*** che vengono usati raramente (fortuna e debito).
 (Garzanti e Hoepli)

Il dizionario etimologico non spiega l'origine del significato più comune ***"[a detta di](http://www.etimo.it/?term=detta)"***.

Potrebbe derivare da uno degli altri due usi? Qual è l'origine di questo modo di dire?

Comment: Sono un po' confuso. Non è esattamente il significato di *detta* come participio passato di *dire*? Quali sono i motivi per supporre un'origine particolare?

Comment: @DenisNardin -         Perchè "detta" e non "detto"? E' un termine che è sopravvissuto solo in questa accezione. Forse veniva usato comunemente anche in altri contesti. Che derivi da "dire" è ovvio, ma penso ci sia una storia che abbia portato all'uso di questo modo di dire. Il dizionario etimologico fa riferimento anche a "ditta". Cosa vuol dire?

Comment: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/detta/ Significato 1, *atto del dire, cosa detta*, immagino ci fosse un *cosa* che è caduto con l'uso. Ditta credo che sia semplicemente una grafia arcaica alternativa